# Power Query M code for conditional column

Tags: dax, powerquery

Please can you help me fix this code

if(([User Email] ="@faccc.com") & "UID" &[User ID]&[User Email]) else [User Email]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

could be anything

maybe

```
#"step" = if [User Email] ="@faccc.com" then "UID" &[User ID]&[User Email] else [User Email]
```

or

```
#"step" = if Text.EndsWith([User Email]) ="@faccc.com" then "UID" &[User ID]&[User Email] else [User Email]
```